# Error when resample dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas

I create a dataframe

```
df5 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/Listeequipement.csv',delimiter=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
df5['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df5['TIMESTAMP'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
df5['date'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.date
df5['time'] = df5['TIMESTAMP'].dt.time
date_debut = pd.to_datetime('2015-08-01 23:10:00')
date_fin = pd.to_datetime('2015-10-01 00:00:00')
df5 = df5[(df5['TIMESTAMP'] >= date_debut) & (df5['TIMESTAMP'] < date_fin)]
df5.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8645 entries, 145 to 8789
Data columns (total 9 columns):
TIMESTAMP                 8645 non-null datetime64[ns]
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7    8645 non-null float64
ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8    8645 non-null float64
date                      8645 non-null object
time                      8645 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 675.4+ KB
```

I try to resample it per day like this :

```
df5.index = pd.to_datetime(df5.index)
df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
df5 = df5.resample('1d').mean()
```

But I get a problem :

> ```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          1944             try:
>       -> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          1946             except KeyError:
>
> ```
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> ```
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> ```
> KeyError: 'TIMESTAMP'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-109-bf3238788c3e> in <module>()
>       1 df5.index = pd.to_datetime(df5.index)
> ----> 2 df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
>       3 df5 = df5.resample('1d').mean()
>
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ```
>
> in set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
>          2835                 names.append(None)
>          2836             else:
>       -> 2837                 level = frame[col]._values
>          2838                 names.append(col)
>          2839                 if drop:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ```
>
> in **getitem**(self, key)
>          1995             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
>          1996         else:
>       -> 1997             return self._getitem_column(key)
>          1998 
>          1999     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> ```
>
> in _getitem_column(self, key)
>          2002         # get column
>          2003         if self.columns.is_unique:
>       -> 2004             return self._get_item_cache(key)
>          2005 
>          2006         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
> ```
>
> in _get_item_cache(self, item)
>          1348         res = cache.get(item)
>          1349         if res is None:
>       -> 1350             values = self._data.get(item)
>          1351             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
>          1352             cache[item] = res
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py
> ```
>
> in get(self, item, fastpath)
>          3288 
>          3289             if not isnull(item):
>       -> 3290                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>          3291             else:
>          3292                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>          1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>          1946             except KeyError:
>       -> 1947                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>          1948 
>          1949         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> ```
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4154)()
>
> pandas\index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\index.c:4018)()
>
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)()
>
> ```
> pandas\hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
> ```
>
> (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)()
>
> ```
> KeyError: 'TIMESTAMP'
> ```

Any idea please to help me to resolve this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: When you allocate `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df,index)` you create an index that has the wrong dates. Then you call `df.set_index['TS']` this instead of allocating TS as the new index can sometimes cause a `reset_index` to occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `pd.to_datetime` and try `df.set_index` directly:

```
*df5.index = pd.to_datetime(df5.index)* # Delete this one
df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
df5 = df5.resample('1d').mean()
```

Comment: Ok thank t you it works, can you explain me why I have to remove it?  Thank you

Comment: Ok I still have a question sir please : Why after reasmpling the data frame , I loose date and time columns?

Comment: Can you post another question with that? and have a sample of the dataframe before and after sampling so I can see what happened. thanks

Answer (score 1):

this below part should be written as
df5 = df5.set_index('TIMESTAMP ')
i think problem is with quotation mark , may be there is some gap between TIMESTAMP and last quotation mark , it would be like "TIMESTAMP " OR " TIMESTAMP " OR " TIMESTAMP"
This can be solution.
i have used google colab to resolve there i have found this solution in my case key error was same , google colab automatically verify and give a option to choose a index to be given which is already quoted